# Changing the index value multiple times

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so for a school assignment I have to make arrays and print out the index of the array countries 3 or more different times and im not sure on how to do it. This is a runestone assignment if this help by the way

Error: Need to get 3 or more different numbers to print index of said country

```
public class Countries
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
       // 1. Declare 4 arrays and initialize them to the given values.
       // Countries: China, Egypt, France, Germany, India, Japan, Kenya, Mexico, United Kingdom, United States
       // Capitals: Beijing, Cairo, Paris, Berlin, New Delhi, Tokyo, Nairobi, Mexico City, London, Washington D.C.
       // Languages: Chinese, Arabic, French, German, Hindi, Japanese, Swahili, Spanish, English, English
       // Filenames for map images: China.jpg, Egypt.jpg, France.jpg, Germany.jpg, India.jpg, Japan.jpg, Kenya.jpg, Mexico.jpg, UK.jpg, US.jpg
      String[] Countries = {"China", "Egypt", "France", "Germany", "India", "Japan", "Kenya", "Mexico", "United Kingdom", "United States"};
      String[] Capitals = {"Beijing", "Cairo", "Paris", "Berlin", "New Delhi", "Tokyo", "Nairobi", "Mexico City", "London", "Washington D.C."};
      String[] Languages = {"Chinese", "Arabic", "French", "German", "Hindi", "Japanese", "Swahili", "Spanish", "English", "English"};
      String[] Filenames = {"China.jpg", "Egypt.jpg", "France.jpg", "Germany.jpg", "India.jpg", "Japan.jpg", "Kenya.jpg", "Mexico.jpg", "UK.jpg", "US.jpg"};
       // 2. Pick a random number up to the length of one of the arrays and save in the variable index
      int index = ((int)Math.random() * Capitals.length);

       // 3. Print out the info in each array using the random index
      System.out.println(Countries[index]);
      System.out.println(Capitals[index]);
      System.out.println(Languages[index]);

       // Example of showing image files using an array called images (your array name above may be different)
       // (this will only work in Active Code)
      Countries obj = new Countries();
      obj.printHTMLimage(Filenames[index]);
      

   }

   // This method will just work in Active Code which interprets html
   public void printHTMLimage(String filename)
   {
     String baseURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bhoffman0/CSAwesome/master/_sources/Unit6-Arrays/6-1-images/";
     System.out.print("<img src=" + baseURL + filename + ">");
   }
  }
```

Comment: Put the  code in a loop that iterates 3 times?  What is the expected output?

Comment: well the expected output would need to be this https://imgur.com/a/nGfdvG1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the code you wrote is passing the steps just fine. If you are able to get something working 1 time, but need it to happen more than once you are going to need a **loop**. That way you can preform the same set of actions as many times as you like.

```
public class Countries
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
       // 1. Declare 4 arrays and initialize them to the given values.
       // Countries: China, Egypt, France, Germany, India, Japan, Kenya, Mexico, United Kingdom, United States
       // Capitals: Beijing, Cairo, Paris, Berlin, New Delhi, Tokyo, Nairobi, Mexico City, London, Washington D.C.
       // Languages: Chinese, Arabic, French, German, Hindi, Japanese, Swahili, Spanish, English, English
       // Filenames for map images: China.jpg, Egypt.jpg, France.jpg, Germany.jpg, India.jpg, Japan.jpg, Kenya.jpg, Mexico.jpg, UK.jpg, US.jpg
      String[] Countries = {"China", "Egypt", "France", "Germany", "India", "Japan", "Kenya", "Mexico", "United Kingdom", "United States"};
      String[] Capitals = {"Beijing", "Cairo", "Paris", "Berlin", "New Delhi", "Tokyo", "Nairobi", "Mexico City", "London", "Washington D.C."};
      String[] Languages = {"Chinese", "Arabic", "French", "German", "Hindi", "Japanese", "Swahili", "Spanish", "English", "English"};
      String[] Filenames = {"China.jpg", "Egypt.jpg", "France.jpg", "Germany.jpg", "India.jpg", "Japan.jpg", "Kenya.jpg", "Mexico.jpg", "UK.jpg", "US.jpg"};

       // Loop through this logic 3 times
       for(int i=1; i<= 3; i++){

        // 2. Pick a random number up to the length of one of the arrays and save in the variable index
        int index = ((int)Math.random() * Capitals.length);

         // 3. Print out the info in each array using the random index
        System.out.println(Countries[index]);
        System.out.println(Capitals[index]);
        System.out.println(Languages[index]);

         // Example of showing image files using an array called images (your array name above may be different)
         // (this will only work in Active Code)
        Countries obj = new Countries();
        obj.printHTMLimage(Filenames[index]);
      }

   }

   // This method will just work in Active Code which interprets html
   public void printHTMLimage(String filename)
   {
     String baseURL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bhoffman0/CSAwesome/master/_sources/Unit6-Arrays/6-1-images/";
     System.out.print("<img src=" + baseURL + filename + ">");
   }
  }
```

By including the line `int index = ((int)Math.random() * Capitals.length);` inside of the loop, this allow us to run the same set of instructions 3 times, but using a new index value each time.

Comment: I tried your said example but each time it does it, it just has the same index value over and over again.

Comment: Edit: Never mind your way did fix my problem I just needed to add an extra ( or two to the math.random

Comment: @ChristopherAcosta remember to accept his answer since it solved your problem.